# MongoDB object not updating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on a database system using MongoDB. I am trying to save the current date and time, then update it if the same barcode on ID cards is scanned twice, thrice, etc... However, the $set will not update the item. I have already looked at MongoDB documentation and other Stack Overflow posts, but nothing seems to work. Other Stack Overflow posts suggested adding

```
{ new: true }
```

and

```
( overwrite: true }
```

I tried these both separately and in tandem neither worked.

My Code:

```
Student.findOne({StudNum: studNum}, function(err, studNumItem) {
   if (err) {
    res.send("MongoDB Error: " + err);
    return false;
   }
   if (!studNumItem) {
    var myData = new Student({ StudNum: studNum, Attendance : 1, LastDateTimeAttended : {
        Year: year, Month: month, Day: day, Hours: hours, Min: min, Sec: sec
    }});
    myData.save()
      .then(item => {
        res.send("saved to database: " + studNum + ", with attendance " + Attendance + "");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.send("unable to save to database: " + studNum + ", for attendance " + Attendance + "");
      });
    }
    else{
      var conditions = {StudNum: studNum};
      var update = {$inc : { Attendance: 1 }, $set : {
        "Year": year, "Month": month, "Day": day, "Hours": hours, "Min": min, "Sec": sec
      }};
      Student.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, { new: true }, function (err)
      {
          if (err) // If error
          {
            res.send(err);
          }
          else {
            res.send("Checked in!")
          }
      });
 }
```

});

And my Schema:

```
var studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
StudNum: String,
Attendance: Number,
LastDateTimeAttended: {
  Year: Number,
  Month: Number,
  Day: Number,
  Hours: Number,
  Min: Number,
  Sec: Number
}
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Just to clarify, saving the item works fine, but updating the item does not, also no errors are thrown while updating.

Comment: your all the fields are nested inside `LastDateTImeAttended`... You need to use .dot notation to `$set` them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I'm not sure it is your find one and update that is the issue. I believe since what you are trying to update is a nested object, you need to prepend it with the top level property to get mongoose to save it. Since those properties don't exist at a top level, mongoose is just throwing it away.

```js
var update = {
    $inc : {
        Attendance: 1
    },
    $set : {
        "LastDateTimeAttended.Year": year,
        "LastDateTimeAttended.Month": month,
        "LastDateTimeAttended.Day": day,
        "LastDateTimeAttended.Hours": hours,
        "LastDateTimeAttended.Min": min,
        "LastDateTimeAttended.Sec": sec
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who don`t know the cause of the issue, it also may be that the variable is not declared in the scheme causing any alteration to be halted and ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try saving you date as a string.
`LastDateTimeAttended` in your model should expect a string, and new Student constructor should create `LastDateTimeAttended` variable by calling

```
let date = new Date();
LastDateTimeAttended = date.toString();
```

your new schema should look like

```
var studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    StudNum: {type: String, required: true},
    Attendance: {type: Number, required: true},
    LastDateTimeAttended: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

you should then be able to update your mongodb document
`Student.findOneandUpdate(conditions, update, callback)`. [see working with mongoose Model.findOneandUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)